# Want to make perl code for oauth2 work in Java "curl -H 'Authorization: Bearer:<TOKEN> https://canvas.instructure.com/api/v1";

Tags: java, curl, httpurlconnection, urlconnection, oauth-2.0

I am getting an error that I am unauthorized.. RESPONSE CODE 401
The token I am using works in perl..

This is what I have tried till now:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try {
        String auth = returnAuth(); //getting token from a file.
        //System.out.println(auth);
        String url1= "https://canvas.instructure.com/api/v1";
        URL url = new URL(url1+"/courses");
        HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");     

        //connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + auth);

        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer "+auth);
        System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Response code:" + connection.getResponseCode());
        System.out.println("Response message:" + connection.getResponseMessage());

            // Read the response:
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            connection.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line);
            }
            reader.close();
            System.out.println(response.toString());
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();           
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { 
    try {
    String auth = returnAuth(); //getting token from a file.
    String url1= "https://canvas.instructure.com/api/v1/courses";
    URL url = new URL(url1);
    HttpsURLConnection connection =(HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");     

    connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer "+auth);
    System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Response code:" + connection.getResponseCode());
    System.out.println("Response message:" + connection.getResponseMessage());

        // Read the response:
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        connection.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        reader.close();
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();           
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have it commented out but every Oauth server I've dealt with would be "Bearer <token>" - one space and no colon.

Comment: Sorry for that mistake. But tried it without colon and with a space.. still not working

Comment: I'd have to then ask how you're generating the token - they have a limited lifespan and they need to be valid.  Can I suggest using something like Postman (https://www.getpostman.com/) Firebug (https://getfirebug.com/) to get the auth working first and *then* get the Java code working.

Comment: I"ll generate a new token and try if it works and also will try to work on your suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You set the parameters AFTER you called!

Change your code to first set the authentication, then open the connection.

```
String url1= "https://canvas.instructure.com/api/v1";
URL url = new URL(url1+"/courses");
connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer "+auth);
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");     

//now you can open the connection...

HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

Comment: Method returnAuth() was not returning Token Properly. Worked when I openConnection() before setting Request. Thanks.